# How to get the list of a flash SWF flashvars parameters

Tags: variables, parameters, flash, flashvars

I have a flash file (swf) developed by somebody else. I don't have access to the list of flashvars parameters it can take and I don't have any HTML to learn from it.

Is there any method (like AC3 action script) that I can use to extract the list of parameters?